# lrange command on sails-redis

Tags: node.js, redis, sails.js, waterline

I'm new to sails.js.
I want to issue a redis command  on sails-redis like this,

```
lrange SPECIFIC_KEY 0 10
```

but I can't see how should I write codes in my model for it.
Documentation for sails-redis and waterline give me no hint to me.

What should I do for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Redis commands like `LRANGE` don't exist at the Waterline ORM level.  You'll need to access the underlying `node_redis` adapter to use them.  You can do this using the Waterline collection's `native` method.  If you have a `User` collection in Sails, for example, it would be:

```
User.native(function(err, collection) {

   // At this point "collection" is the native node_redis collection
   collection.lrange("someKey", 0, 10, function(err, result) {

       console.log(result);

   });

});
```

Documentation for the underlying `node_redis` adapter is [here](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis).